# DEL as comment in texinfo source file

Tags: texinfo

In info file texinfo.info, section 2.2 Comments, is the statement "Everything on the line after the DEL will be ignored." I have no experience with texinfo source files or TeX, and would appreciate an explanation/example.
I spent yesterday afternoon searching and found nothing. Is this something new to texinfo?
I've tried EsCtlSeqs such as ^D and various category codes such as \catcode127=14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEL is ASCII 127 so control-? (as ? is ASCII 63=127-64)

`texinfo.tex` has

```
% DEL is a comment character, in case @c does not suffice.
\catcode`\^^? = 14
```

So you can use ctrl-? in place of the traditional TeX `%`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. To invoke in emacs, I used C-q C-BackSPC --> ^?. In vim, C-v C-BackSPC in insert mode. The explanation should be in info texinfo. Sorry I can't upvote.

Comment: @user244881 in emacs I'd use `C-q C-?`  to enter it as control ? or `C-q <backspace>` to enter it directly (you don't need control-backspace)